# Fade in, Fade out Divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I'm trying to build a webpage that is essentially one page, but with four 'hidden' divs that will fade in and out of visibility when you click on menu buttons along the bottom.

I would like to put a 'close' button at the top of each of these divs so you can 'close' that div - but it would be great if the div still faded out on its own when a new menu item is clicked. So far I've created the div boxes and the links using css and html, but I'm an absolute newbie when it comes to javascript. Here's the code I have so far

HTML:

```
<div class="menu">
    <a class="portfolio" href="http://www.google.com"> Portfolio </a> | <a  class="aboutme" href="http://www.google.com"> About Me </a> | <a class="education" href="http://www.google.com"> Education</a> | <a class="contact" href="http://www.google.com"> Contact</a>
</div>
<div>`
```

(NOTE: I only put google as the link target because I didn't know what else to put).

CSS:

```
.aboutmewindow
{
    width:583px;
    height:557px;
    border-bottom-style:dashed;
    position:absolute;
    top:0px;
    z-index:2;  
}

.portfoliowindow
{
    width:583px;
    height:557px;
    border-bottom-style:dashed;
    position:absolute;
    top:0px;
    z-index:2;  
}

.educationwindow
{
    width:583px;
    height:557px;
    border-bottom-style:dashed;
    position:absolute;
    top:0px;
    z-index:2;  
}

.contactwindow
{
    width:583px;
    height:557px;
    border-bottom-style:dashed;
    position:absolute;
    top:0px;
    z-index:2;  
}`
```

I've tried writing a little bit of the javascript on my own, but it's seriously out of my depth at this point. I'm going to keep going through tutorials though, so hopefully I'll get the hang of it.

Anyone have any suggestions? Or good tutorials?

Thanks!

Comment: can you provide the little bit of javascript u have tried?

Comment: Surely that's not all of the relevant HTML? None of the CSS refers to any of that stuff.

Comment: Oh, whoops, you're right, I forgot to include the div containers. Sorry!

Comment: Yep, SO isn't a free freelance service. Try it yourself and then ask for specific help.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/vMjGH/

Comment: Not related to the JavaScipt question but here's how I reckon you should've structured the menu: http://jsfiddle.net/aZhzY/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a slightly outdated (August, 2012) tutorial showing you the HTML, CSS, and JavaScript required to fade elements in, fade them out, and fade them to a specific opacity.

http://www.mkyong.com/jquery/jquery-fadein-fadeout-and-fadeto-example/

You're essentially trying to learn about the following:

- [`.fadeIn()`](http://api.jquery.com/fadeIn/)
- [`.fadeOut()`](http://api.jquery.com/fadeOut/)
- [`.fadeTo()`](http://api.jquery.com/fadeTo/)
- [jQuery's `.click()` handler](http://api.jquery.com/click/)
- [jQuery's `.on()` handler](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

Comment: Wow, thanks so much for that! I'll give it a try and see how I go. Thanks :)

Comment: Not a problem. Once you learn how to use jQuery's event handlers (for click, hover, etc.), you'll be amazed at how well you can manipulate the elements on your site.

Answer (score 1):

you can try this its a simple example but without all your markup and code you can get the idea .. requires jQuery

http://jsfiddle.net/YnzRV/9/

```
$(function(){

    $("#main > .box").not(":first").hide();

    $(".menu").on("click", "a", function(){

        var $this = $(this),
            dataBox = $this.data("box");

        $("#main > .box").hide();
        $("."+dataBox).fadeIn(400);

        return false;
    });

});
```

if you check the jsfiddle you will see how i added data attributes that get passed through the click handler to tell it which div to show using the data attributes

Answer (score 0):

You can use `fadeIn()` or `fadeOut()`.

Use it like this:

```
$('selector').fadeIn(); // you can use time in ms, inside ()
```

Similarly, you can use `fadeOut` too. But keep in mind, that you have the latest version of jQuery linked to your web page.

Links:

http://jquery.com